# Set parameter key in an array of strings javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am pretty sure this already exists because it is basic array knowledge but cannot seem to find it.

I have an array of strings like this:

```
my_array = ['first', 'second', 'third']
```

I want to set the keys for each array element but with a parameter. The expected result should be something like this:

```
 new_array = [ { my_sting: 'first' },
               { my_sting: 'second' },
               { my_sting: 'third' } ]
```

What I have tried so far is:

```
string_parameter = 'my_string';   
new_array = my_array.map((n: string) => {
                return {
                    string_parameter : n
                };
            });
```

But instead of the key to be 'my_string' it becomes 'string_parameter'

I have also tried looping through the elements

```
string_parameter = 'my_string';     
my_array.forEach(function(element: string) { new_array[string_parameter] = element;});
```

But here I end up with only the last element of the array.

Could someone point me to the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The syntax of your desired output is invalid... `['my_sting' : 'first', 'my_string' : 'second', 'my_string' : 'third']`

Comment: @CertainPerformance just to add, even if this was an object, the syntax would be *valid* but you will still only get one key.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I updated the question with the desired output, I am really sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use string_parameter like this [string_parameter]: n

```
new_array = my_array.map((n: string) => {
            return {
                [string_parameter] : n
            };
        });
```

Hopefully it should work